# How Can I Make AS3 Var Loop move speed on the Y Axis on repeat my university project

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm tring to get the car image to move down the screen on the y Axis and make it a repeat and colide with another object

```
        //creates the new Car
        for (var c:int=0; c<8; c++){
            var newcar = new car();
            newcar.x = 55*c;
            newcar.y = 100;
            EntityArray.push(newcar);
            stage.addChild(newcar);
            trace("Car Created"+c)
            }
```

How to make it colide with the following and remove it from screen

```
        //creates the new Frog
        for (var f:int=0; f<1; f++){
            var newfrog = new frog();
            newfrog.x = 210;
            newfrog.y = 498;
            EntityArray.push(newfrog);
            stage.addChild(newfrog);
            trace("Frog Created"+f)
            }
```

[image][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihsfx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I'm quite pleased to hear that today they still tell you about ActionScript at college, it's a bit hard
to give you advice here since I don't know what they've covered yet.
Generally speaking, you could realize this with a simple game loop, that runs periodically and in it's most simple
form:

- checks user input (in your case most likely pressing left/right to move the frog)
- update game state (move the cars & the frog ; check for collision)
- draw everything to screen

For creating the periodical loop, Flash/ActionScript offers a powerful event called **ENTER_FRAME**. Once started, it
will fire with the framerate of the movie. So if you set your movie to 60fps, it will execute it's callback function
roughly every 17ms.
I assume your instances of Frog and Car extend Flash's Sprite or MovieClip class - so collision detection is also pretty
easy since you can use the inherited **hitTestObject()** method.
To make things a bit easier though I'd recommend that you don't put the reference to the frog instance inside the EntityArray.
Better use a global reference. (Also, you don't need a for-loop because there's just one frog)

As another sidenote, it's quite common that classnames start with a capital letter.

`private var newfrog:frog; // defines a class variable we can access anywhere inside our class`

```
//Later on instantiate new cars and the frog:
for (var c:int=0; c<8; c++){
    var newcar = new car();
    newcar.x = 55*c;
    newcar.y = 100;
    EntityArray.push(newcar);
    stage.addChild(newcar);
}
newfrog = new frog();
newfrog.x = 210;
newfrog.y = 498;
stage.addChild(newfrog);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop); // register an ENTER_FRAME listener for the main game loop

private function loop(e:Event):void
{
    var tempCar:car;
    for(var a:int=0;a<EntityArray.length;a++)
    {
        tempCar=EntityArray[a]; // get a car from the EntityArray
        tempCar.y++; // move it down on screen
        if(tempCar.y>600) // if it's vertical position is greater than 600...
        {
            tempCar.y=0; // ...move it back to the top
        }
        if(newfrog.hitTestObject(tempCar)) // evaluates to true, if a car and the frog's bounding boxes overlap
        {
            trace("there's a collision!"); // do something
        }
    }
}
```